# Write large http response inside the text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a large `request.txt` file with 1.7 million lines of requests. I have a program that writes the response back to the `response.txt` file.  After around 2000 responses, the program stops writing to the `response.txt` file. I am unable to figure out the reason.

here is my code :

```
with open(request,'r',1) as fin, open(response, 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        # json.loads take a string as input and returns a dictionary as output.
        dct = json.loads(line)
        response = requests.post(url_rsl,json=dct)
        response_json = response.json()
        json.dump(response_json, fout)
        fout.write('\n')
```

I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? "Stops writing" is pretty broad - is there any error message given? If you run the program multiple times, does it always stop after the same 2000 requests?

Comment: the program is still running but the file is not being written. There is no error per se.

Comment: insert `print(line)` after `fout.write('\n')` so you can see if the program is stuck or not